# how can I send a file that's inside another folder using express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

why is my browser says that the folder and the folder I wanted to send are don't exist?

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000 || process.env.PORT;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/Structures/index.html');
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('listening on port' + port);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check the path of index.html com your foldering should be like this:

[image]

if your foldering like this:

[image]

user `path` module and `join` path so just try

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000 || process.env.PORT;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    // res.sendFile(__dirname + '../Structures/index.html');
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'../Structures/index.html')) 
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('listening on port' + port);
});
```

Comment: oh.. I forgot to mention this, but the app.js is in its own folder.. does that matter? thank you for answering BTW!

Comment: You're welcome. If this answers your question, please accept it, so both of us gain more reputation and other users can see that this answer solved your problem. See this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers